Selenium: Accessing Child Elements from Identical Parent Elements using CSS Selectors
I am automating the selection of shopping option filters on a web application using Selenium WebDriver. The goal is to interact with filters such as Size, Material, and Price, and then retrieve the list of  tags within these filters to randomly select and click an option.
Website: https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/
Image 1: Parent elements
Image 2: Child elements
Objective: Select a specific filter option (e.g., Material as show in image 2), and get the list of  tags to randomly select one and click on it.
Parent-Child HTML structure, there are 12 'filter-options-item' classes (refer image 1):
<div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item allow active" role="presentation" data-collapsible="true">
  <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
    Material
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
    <ol class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <a href="https://example.com">Cotton</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="https://example.com">Polyester</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="https://example.com">Wool</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>


....
I've tried using following approach with XPATH and it works, but I don't prefer xpath and use it only as last resort. Using CSS selectors for this task is challenging because CSS does not support selecting elements based on their text content (e.g., text()='Material'). And without text() attribute, I don't know how to access specific filter option
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from random import choice


material = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='filter-options-title' and text()='Material']"))
)
material.click()


material_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "following-sibling::div[@class='filter-options-content']//ol//li"))
)


choice(material_list).click()


My question : Is there a better way to handle scenarios where the parent elements have the same attributes, and you want to access specific children without relying on text content in CSS selectors?

I don't think there is a general solution using css, you could loop through all the elements and check their text content, but at that point just use XPATH. In this site's case the hrefs of anchor tags contain the option name, so you can select based on that. Or you can use BeautifulSoup's find() but that's not really css.

Thanks for your response. I've decided to use XPATH as it's the best option available.
